# Automatically escape special characters of parameter value passed to sqlcmd

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd, invoke-sqlcmd

I have a stored procedure that accepts a script and execute it against the database:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ExecuteScript]
  @Script nvarchar(MAX)
AS
EXECUTE sp_executesql @Script;
```

When I call this procedure from command-line with [sqlcmd Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15) like:

```
sqlcmd -E -d <mydb> -Q "usp_ExecuteScript @Script=$(script)" /v script=my_script
```

where my_script is `SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName ='John'`, I am forced to escape all special characters such as 'qoute' manually otherwise, it fails to execute.
This gets cumbersome when I am looping through a number of long and complex scripts to pass them as @Script argument to be executed this way.

Do you have any idea to get it work?

Comment: What's the point of that procedure? You could use `sp_execute` directly.

Comment: This looks to me like an [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). To avoid escaping, you could execute the proc via a parameterized query in PowerShell. Note sure what value SQLCMD provides in this case.

Comment: @stickybit, because I do some extra stuff in the usp_ExecuteScript procedure as well.

Comment: Then show us that. This just looks like a way to let your RDBMS be easily injected into.